# How to Consume App Engine Task Queue Via Compute Engine Instance

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, task-queue

I have a Google App Engine Application with a Task Queue. I'm thoroughly confused on how to create a Compute Engine Instance that can lease tasks from the Task Queue via the Task Queue REST API.

**Keep in mind I am developing/testing locally right now.**

In my queue.yaml file, I define the following taskqueue:

```
- name: videos
  mode: pull
  acl: 
  - user_email: projectID-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  - writer_email: projectID-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

This email address is the default compute engine service account email.

I am creating a Compute Engine instance from my google cloud console for now. I choose the Compute Engine default service account and under `access scopes` I choose `Set access for each API`and then enable task queue.

After I create instance, I ssh via `gcloud compute ssh instance-name`.

I then run the following commands: `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get -y install python-pip`, `sudo pip install google-api-python-client`.

I have a python script on my Google Cloud Storage which I'm able to copy onto my VM via `gsutil cp gs://projectname.appspot.com/script.py`.

I then run my script: `python script.py`.

In my python script, I have the following code:

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = build('taskqueue', 'v1beta2', credentials=credentials)
result = service.tasks().lease(leaseSecs=30, taskqueue='videos', project='project_name', numTasks=1).execute()
```

I was getting a `HttpError 403 "you are not allowed to make this api call"`.

However, I ran the following command `appcfg.py update_queues .` and now I seem to be able to connect to the taskqueue API.

However, I don't seem to be able to lease any tasks. When I print the result from the above code, I get: `{u'kind': u'taskqueue#tasks'}`. However, if I check for `'items' in result` it returns empty. I can verify there are tasks in the taskqueue by going to the dev console at `localhost:8000`

Any help would be MUCH APPRECIATED

Comment: Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction here?

Comment: I guess you publish at localhost and lease tasks form GAE. Do you have and tasks in the queue in the Google App Engine https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/taskqueues for your project?